# domain timeout out after changing dns

Tags: domain-name-system, timeout

We transferd a domain to our server  but it seems to time out a lot. what's confusing is we have lots of other domains on our server that work. I can not see any differences when I use dnsstuff tools any help to what the problem could be would be great

the domain is

debtadvice.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MacBook-Pro-van-Bart:~ ikbenbart$ dig debtadvice.net

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3 <<>> debtadvice.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10396
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;debtadvice.net.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
debtadvice.net.     14400   IN  A   172.31.255.94

;; Query time: 280 msec
;; SERVER: 10.95.134.12#53(10.95.134.12)
;; WHEN: Fri Apr 13 11:26:34 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 48
```

`172.31.255.94` is not an 'internet'-ip. It is part of RFC 1918, dealing with Private Network Addresses.

> 3. Private Address Space
>
>    The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has reserved the
>      following three blocks of the IP address space for private internets:
>
>    10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
>       172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
>       192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)

A lot of routers will just drop the traffic if they are not part of the 172.16/12 prefix. Your site is only accessible inside the same LAN as the server. If you want to make it available to the world, you will have to put a proper WAN-ip in the A-record and route the traffic from the WAN-edge to your server.

Comment: Thank you for your help i will contact are server comopany

Comment: +1 for your MacBook's name. =)